# Output for large correlation matrices in R

Tags: r, formatting, output

From what I've seen, R cannot very easily produce usable output for large correlation matrices (50-100 variables). For instance, "corr.test" or "cor" output is horrendously wrapped (each variable should have only one row and one column, but this is certainly not the case) and does not copy well into Excel for later examination. Is there a way to produce SPSS-like correlation output in R? Namely, correlation matrices that can be copied and pasted easily into something like Excel, where each row and each column pertains to one variable (no wrapping of text), and ideally, sample-sizes and significance values are somehow available. Corr.test provides this information, albeit in an inconvenient format, and when variables exceed output viewer space in R, the output is basically unreadable. Any thoughts would be greatly, greatly appreciated, as I'm frequently working with many variables at once.

Comment: do you mean `cor.test`?  Can you give an example? (By default `cor.test` seems to work only with pairs of variables ...)

Comment: Actually, I guess ?? you're talking about `psych::corr.test`.  Can you confirm?

Comment: I was talking about corr.test from the psych package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with

```
z <- matrix(rnorm(10000),100)
write.csv(cor(z),file="cortmp.csv")
```

? `View(cor(z))` works for me, although I don't know if it's copy-and-pasteable.

For `psych::corr.test`

```
dimnames(z) <- list(1:100,1:100)
z[1,2] <- NA  ## unbalance to induce sample size matrix
ct <- psych::corr.test(z)
write.csv(ct$n,file="ntmp.csv")  ## sample sizes
write.csv(ct$t,file="ttmp.csv")  ## t statistics
write.csv(ct$p,file="ptmp.csv")  ## p-values
```

et cetera.  (See `str(ct)`.)

R's paradigm is that if you want to transfer information to another program you're going to output it to a file rather than copying and pasting it from the console ...

Comment: That does work, Ben. Thanks. I had tried it with corr.test prior to and had issues. I imagine if I wanted matrices of sample sizes and p-values (i.e. significance values) for those corresponding correlations, I'd have to use some sort of subcommands and save those as separate CSV's?